# Generate WCF proxy in unmanaged C++

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2008, wcf, wcf-client

Is there a way to generate WCF proxy for an unmanaged C++?

Thanks,

Mattan

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ATL Service Library: http://atlserver.codeplex.com/
or ATL server project:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seaf2d75(VS.71).aspx

Comment: The use of the ATL service (with sproxy) is problematic:
* Not supported after vs 2003.
* Doesn't work when I use functions that returns Lists/Arrays.
* Doesn't work when the functions gets complex types as parameters.

Comment: In this case, if you're on Windows 7 or windows 2008 R2, You can try using Saphire library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435(VS.85).aspx